# I want specific path color for each node d3

Tags: html, d3.js

The issue is I want to add each node in the tree with different node color, I've tried multiple solutions but no results. Below is my data, how can I change my data to add it to tree with different colors.
This my [Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNbrE.jpg)

```
var treeData = {"name" : "HTTP-GET", "children" : [
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/ ", "children" : [
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/AboutCIIT/Introduction.aspx","children" :[ 
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/AboutCIIT/Introduction.aspx " },
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/AboutCIIT/Introduction.aspx " },
 {"name" : " Embedded Stream ", "children" : [
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/favicon.ico " },
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/favicon.ico " }]}]},
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/AboutCIIT/Introduction.aspx " }, 
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/AboutCIIT/Introduction.aspx " }, 
 {"name" : " Embbeded Stream ", "children" : [
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/favicon.ico " }, 
 {"name" : "  wah.comsats.edu.pk/favicon.ico " }]}]}, 
 {"name" : "  cuonline.ciitwah.edu.pk/ "} 
 ]};
```

Following is my code to visualize tree. I've tried to change the function but instead, it stops visualizing tree.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.node circle { 
 fill: #fff;
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width: 1px;
}
.node text {
 font: 12px sans-serif;
text-color:white;
}
.link {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #ccc;
stroke-width: 3px;
}
body{
background-image: url("gray.png");
}
</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var treeData = {"name" : "HTTP-GET", "children" : [
{"name" : " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/ ", "children" : [
{"name" : " http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald " }, 
{"name" : " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/img/acad.jpg " }, 
{"name" : " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/js/responsiveCarousel.min.js " }, 
{"name" : " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/slides/wahm.jpg " }, 
{"name" : " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/slides/BITA17.jpg " }, 
{"name" : " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/slides/alumni.jpg " }, 
{"name" : " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/img/ann.jpg " }, 
{"name" : " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/img/ann.jpg " }]}, 
{"name" : " https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=nsut&oq=nsut&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i59.613j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 "}, 
{"name" : " https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.nsut.com/&ved=0ahUKEwiq-q3goqbaAhXSxqQKHfLhBDIQFggmMAA "}, 
{"name" : " https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=nust&oq=nust&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.814j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 "}, 
{"name" : " https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/734623083781345280/Kb-33Gf3_normal.jpg "}, 
{"name" : " https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DaGZdo6V4AAJ6PW?format=jpg&name=medium "}, 
{"name" : " https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=patent&oq=patent&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6101j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 "}, 
{"name" : " https://syndication.twitter.com/i/jot "}, 
{"name" : " https://platform.twitter.com/jot.html "}, 
]};



  var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
 width = 1960 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom; 
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate("  
 + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 
  var i = 0,
 duration = 750,
 root;
  var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);
  root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
  root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}
function update(source) {
  var treeData = treemap(root);
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
.data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
.attr('class', 'node')
.attr("transform", function(d) {
 return "translate(" + source.y0 + ", " + source.x0 + ")";
})
.on('click', click);
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
.attr('class', 'node')
.attr('r', 1e-6)
.style("fill", function(d,i) {
return d._childern ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
});
  nodeEnter.append('text')   
   .attr("dy", ".35em")   
  .attr("x", function(d) {   
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
   })      
.attr("text-anchor", function(d) {      
    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";      
})      
.text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);
  nodeUpdate.transition()    
.duration(duration)    
.attr("transform", function(d) {         
return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";     
});
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')    
.attr('r', 10)    
.style("fill", function(d) {        
return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";    
})    
.attr('cursor', 'pointer');
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()      
.duration(duration)      
.attr("transform", function(d) {          
return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";      
})      
.remove();
  nodeExit.select('circle')    
.attr('r', 1e-6);
  nodeExit.select('text')    
.style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')      
.data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")      
.attr("class", "link")      
.attr('d', function(d){        
var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}        
return diagonal(o, o)      
});
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);
  linkUpdate.transition()      
.duration(duration)      
.attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()      
.duration(duration)      
.attr('d', function(d) {        
var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}        
return diagonal(o, o)      
})      
.remove();
  nodes.forEach(function(d){    
d.x0 = d.x;    
d.y0 = d.y;  
});
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
     }
    }
   </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: You need to show your code if you want help.

Comment: I've updated the code for tree.

Comment: It wasn't me who marked this question down by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this will do it,

but be careful to use spaces on both ends of the strings when checking each case. The stumped me for a little while,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
  .node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

  .node text {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    text-color: white;
  }

  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }

  body {
    background-image: url("gray.png");
  }
</style>

<body>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var treeData = {
      "name": "HTTP-GET",
      "children": [{
          "name": " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/ ",
          "children": [{
              "name": " http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald "
            },
            {
              "name": " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/img/acad.jpg "
            },
            {
              "name": " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/js/responsiveCarousel.min.js "
            },
            {
              "name": " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/slides/wahm.jpg "
            },
            {
              "name": " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/slides/BITA17.jpg "
            },
            {
              "name": " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/slides/alumni.jpg "
            },
            {
              "name": " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/img/ann.jpg "
            },
            {
              "name": " http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/img/ann.jpg "
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": " https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=nsut&oq=nsut&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i59.613j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 "
        },
        {
          "name": " https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.nsut.com/&ved=0ahUKEwiq-q3goqbaAhXSxqQKHfLhBDIQFggmMAA "
        },
        {
          "name": " https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=nust&oq=nust&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.814j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 "
        },
        {
          "name": " https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/734623083781345280/Kb-33Gf3_normal.jpg "
        },
        {
          "name": " https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DaGZdo6V4AAJ6PW?format=jpg&name=medium "
        },
        {
          "name": " https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=patent&oq=patent&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6101j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 "
        },
        {
          "name": " https://syndication.twitter.com/i/jot "
        },
        {
          "name": " https://platform.twitter.com/jot.html "
        },
      ]
    };



    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 90,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 90
      },
      width = 1960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" +
        margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var i = 0,
      duration = 750,
      root;
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
      return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);

    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children
        d._children.forEach(collapse)
        d.children = null
      }
    }

    function update(source) {
      var treeData = treemap(root);
      var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180
      });

      function colorSwitch(d) {
        console.log("I am in colorSwitch");

        switch (d.data.name) {
          case 'wah.comsats.edu.pk/':
            return "yellow";
            break;
          case 'wah.comsats.edu.pk/AboutCIIT/Introduction.aspx':
            return "green";
            break;
          case 'Pwah.comsats.edu.pk/favicon.ico':
            return "blue";
            break;
          default:
            // console.log('There's something happening in here, what it is ain't exactly clear.');
            return "blue";
            break;
        }
      }

      var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y0 + ", " + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on('click', click);
      nodeEnter.append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('r', 1e-6)
      // .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      // return d._childern ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      // .style("fill", "pink");

      nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });
      var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);
      nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });
      nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 10)
        // return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          switch (d.data.name) {
            case ' http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/ ':
              return "yellow";
              break;
            case ' https://platform.twitter.com/jot.html ':
              return "green";
              break;
            case ' http://wah.comsats.edu.pk/slides/BITA17.jpg ':
              return "blue";
              break;
            default:
              return "#f23567"; //or use hex colors
              break;
          }
        })
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer');
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();
      nodeExit.select('circle')
        .attr('r', 1e-6);
      nodeExit.select('text')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);
      var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
        .data(links, function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });
      var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        });
      var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);
      linkUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          return diagonal(d, d.parent)
        });
      var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        })
        .remove();
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });

      function diagonal(s, d) {

        path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
         C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
           ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
           ${d.y} ${d.x}`

        return path
      }

      function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of an array, how can I use Switch to assign colors.

Comment: That is not difficult. Can you provide full code, I can't see what version of d3 you are using or how you are using d3. Are you using a CDN?

Comment: I presume you want a color for each type of name. Is that correct?

Comment: I've updated complete code. Yes, I want color for each name type in tree data. D3 ver 4.13.0

Comment: Is this what you needed?

Comment: Yes, this was what I was asking. Thanks a a lot.

Comment: Is it the actually path between nodes that you want to specify color of?

Comment: Any(path or node), just want to highlight the specific data.